# microsoft sql express 2012 authentication connection issues - can't login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I am a novice when it comes to Windows networking authentication, as well as just getting my feet wet with SQL Express, so please bear with me, hopefully this is a simple fix but so far the obvious fixes I have found in forums have not solved it.

I am trying to set up a geodatabase to be accessible by remote PC's running ESRI's ArcMap with standard license.

I have installed MS SQL Express 2012 as well as necessary components from the 2008 release to be able to access geodatabases.

I can successfully connect to the database from within ArcMap on the machine that is serving it, so I know the server is working.

However if I try and set up a connection on a remote machine I get authentication errors.  I can confirm the server machine is seeing the connection attempt and the firewall is letting in the TCP/IP, as I can see in SQL Management Studio Express's log on the server machine logging the failed attempts.

I get two errors depending on how i try and connect, if I use windows authentication I get a message that the domain is untrusted so i can't use windows authentication.  If I use database authentication I get a message that login failed and to check login/pwd/server.  As mentioned before I know the server part seems to be correct.

In SQL Management configuration I have added a user to the DB and given it a password, I have also switched authentication over to both windows authentication and db authentication.  However if I select db authentication at the connect dialog and put in the user/pwd I still get an error.

I have tried to add my remote machine's IP to the trusted domains on the server PC, but not sure I did that right.  Still get errors that say the domain is untrusted if i try windows authentication.

So not sure where to turn next, or what info you folks might require to sort this out.  Any leads are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Windows auth requires a domain relationship for a remote machine to work. Are your machines actually part of a domain? Are you logging into the remote computer with a domain account? Also have you confirmed that the firewall isn't enabled and you have the protocols enabled? I've created an answer with some pointers - but more information like the error message number and state and details on your setup would help others give more.

Answer (score 1):

More information would help here and I've asked those questions in the comments. That said - a few thoughts:

Basically to access a SQL Server database you need a few things:

1. A login - this gets you into the server itself. This is not a database user, but a login at the instance level (In SSMS this is the top most security, not the security under a database.)
2. That login being mapped to a user - now there are exceptions but for the purposes here - you need that login to then be granted access to the database. This would be security found at the database level.
3. Permissions - you'll need permissions of some sort to do something in SQL.
4. SQL Server needs to have the protocol enabled that you are trying to connect with. Also if there is a firewall, the port (default is 1433 for TCP port) needs to be open.

When there are connection issues like you describe it is normally around something like not actually being on a domain but trying to use windows auth, a password mismatch, not having access to a default database selected for a login or an actual network issue like a firewall.

These are two older posts but they are fantastic resources for troubleshooting connectivity to SQL Server. This first [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/) is from the SQL Server protocols team and describes the steps to troubleshooting connectivity issues. This second [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/) is from the SQL Server connectivity team blog describing the various login failure messages and their states and how to troubleshoot each state.